# Generate Fillable PDF form using SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, pdf-generation

Can anyone suggest me or point me in the right direction if there is a way to generate a fillable pdf form using SQL Reporting services? Are there any third party plugins on the report server that can provide the fillable form rendering options or if there is a way we could convert the pdf format of the report to fillable form by using some API. Can you please point me in the right direction.

Thanks,
Ajay

Answer (score -2):

I've never heard of such a tool, and a search didn't return any different answer.

One option you have is:

1. Create an editable PDF file with the same layout of your SSRS report
2. Create a WCF service, controller method, or anything your app is with
   logic to get the same info
3. Create a method to fill the editable form using [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) with
   your data
4. Send the PDF file to the user.

Have you ever considered this?

> For number one you can use Acrobat Pro, CutePDF or any other tool you
>   feel confortable with.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, although not the kind of answer i was hoping for. Looks like there is no real solution to address this issue. It has to be either ITextSharp or other utilities to write into the Fillable Forms through code, since there is no tool on SSRS to support Fillable form rendering option. We do not want to maintain two different versions of the report one rdl and the other Fillable form. Since there is no other alternative we will have to stick with editing the Fillable forms through code. I wish there is a better solution ot this..